# How do I add git params to an IntelliJ Idea code template?

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to create a file header template using a few variables. The only one I couldn't create until now is something like:

`// Author: ${GIT_USERNAME}`

Does anyone have an idea how I could manage to do that? In Eclipse it's like this:

`// Author: ${git_name:git_config(user.name)}`

But in IntelliJ it doesn't work, neither can I find plugins that help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to upvote on the related issue in JetBrains issues tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145370 .

As a workaround you can add `-Duser.name=some_user` under `Help | Edit Custom VM Options`, restart the IDE and define the following file header:

[image]

All predefined File Template variables are listed here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-template-variables.html .

Comment: I don't see how this workaround is better than just hardcoding the actual user name per user in the project. ^^' But yeah thanks for linking the issue!